# GitHub Actions: Can't set env variable

Tags: github, github-actions

I am trying to set a simple environment variable based on the branch name, but I cannot get it to work. Based on the logs, the env var seems to be set correctly, but it is still empty afterwards:

```
TF_VAR_project_name=staging >> /home/runner/work/_temp/_runner_file_commands/set_env_51dc1c8d-60b9-47bd-b91e-f315cd9349a7
```

--

```
name: "Terraform"

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
      - staging
  pull_request:

jobs:
  terraform:
    name: "Terraform"
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Get branch names
        id: branch-name
        uses: tj-actions/branch-names@v4

      - name: For PR, get base ref branch name
        if: github.event_name == 'pull_request'
        run: |
          echo "TF_VAR_project_name=${{ steps.branch-name.outputs.base_ref_branch }} >> $GITHUB_ENV"

      - name: For push, get current branch name
        if: github.event_name == 'push'
        run: |
          echo "TF_VAR_project_name=${{ steps.branch-name.outputs.current_branch }} >> $GITHUB_ENV"

      - name: Test1
        run: |
          echo "$TF_VAR_project_name"

      - name: Set is prod based on the branch
        run: |
          echo "TF_VAR_is_prod=$(( $TF_VAR_project_name == prod ? true : false ))" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

Complete Log:
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: You used $(( instead of ${{ on this step in your workflow. Moreover, I'm not sure you need to use ? true : false here as well as the expression with your_var == prod should already return a boolean 

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! What I am wondering about is that in Test1, the TF_VAR_project_name env variable seems to be empty.

Comment: It could be related to the `"` position on your expression: `echo "TF_VAR_project_name=${{ steps.branch-name.outputs.base_ref_branch }} >> $GITHUB_ENV"` should be written `echo "TF_VAR_project_name=${{ steps.branch-name.outputs.base_ref_branch }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV` according to [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-environment-variable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two syntax problems with your workflow:

**FIRST**:

The syntax used to set variables has `"` incorrectly used:

```
    run: |
      echo "TF_VAR_project_name=${{ steps.branch-name.outputs.base_ref_branch }} >> $GITHUB_ENV"
```

Should be:

```
    run: |
      echo "TF_VAR_project_name=${{ steps.branch-name.outputs.base_ref_branch }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

Before the `>> $GITHUB_ENV` ([documentation reference](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-environment-variable))

**SECOND**:

The syntax used at the last step uses `$(( ... ))` instead of `${{ .. }}`:

```
  - name: Set is prod based on the branch
    run: |
      echo "TF_VAR_is_prod=$(( $TF_VAR_project_name == prod ? true : false ))" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

Should be:

```
  - name: Set is prod based on the branch
    run: |
      echo "TF_VAR_is_prod=${{ $TF_VAR_project_name == prod ? true : false }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

As you used on other steps.